# Magento 2 version 2.1.2, undefined index PK_CMS_PAGE

Tags: php, magento2

Installing a magento 2 site locally. Half developed by anothr developer. 
His version of the site on his machine seems to be working fine. My version gives an error relating to CMS pages, both in the admin->content->pages section....and the site frontend homepage:

```
Notice : Undefined index: PK_CMS_PAGE in /vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/EntityMetadata.php on line 96
```

Not much information found relating to this issue online.
**setup:upgrade** has been run, and completes fine.

Can anyone point me in the right direction in getting this issue resolved?

Comment: have you perform setup:di:compile?

Answer (score 2):

cms_page table in the database was missing its primary key!

Answer (score 0):

You probably get max_execution_time exceeded on installing/import project db:
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\dbi\DBIMysqli.php on line ...

You need to:
1. change max_execution_time in php.ini:
max_execution_time=-1
2. xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php:
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 0;
3. restart apache and mysql
3. drop broken database and import/reinstall your magento 2

Answer (score 0):

for mage 2.1 version this works for me

```
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ && rm -rf pub/static/_cache && rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ && rm -rf var/cache && rm -rf var/generation && rm -Rf var/di && rm -Rf var/page_cache

bin/magento c:f
```